# iOS - segmentedControl disappears after using searchBar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uisegmentedcontrol

Through Storyboard, I have created a ViewController with a UITableView and a SegmentedControl on top. Programatially, I have added a SearchController as the TableView's header.

This is what happens when I launch the app:
It works perfectly.
[image: image1]

[image: image 2]

But when I click on the search bar, it already messes up a bit. It's easy to fix by hiding the SegmentedControl though.

Now the problem appears when I finish my search:
[image]

The SegmentedControl disappears. Whenever I click on the searchbar again, it comes back, just like in the picture number 2, but if I cancel again, it disappears.

I have tried removing it from the view and adding it again once the user stops searching, but it changes nothing. Here is my code:

```
    searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:nil];
searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self;
searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = NO;
searchController.searchBar.delegate = self;
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar;
searchController.searchBar.scopeButtonTitles = @[];
self.definesPresentationContext = YES;
[searchController.searchBar sizeToFit];
```

What can I change?

Comment: Have you tried not using a segmented control and just using the scope bar of the uisearchcontroller's searchbar? It will remove a lot of the layout issues you are having.

Comment: Pretty crazy I never thought about this. It works, but not completely...how can I always display the scope bar, even when the user is not searching?

Answer (score 0):

```
searchController.searchBar.showsScopeBar = YES;
```

Comment: Did you add it at the end of all of this: searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:nil];
searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self;
searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = NO;
searchController.searchBar.delegate = self;
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar;
searchController.searchBar.scopeButtonTitles = @[];
self.definesPresentationContext = YES;
[searchController.searchBar sizeToFit];?

Comment: Yes, and that was the issue. It works now. Please update your answer to make it more clear and complete and I will accept it! Thank you so much.

Comment: Just one issue. On the first click on the search bar, it overlaps with the scope bar. If I cancel and then click again, it's perfect. How can I change htis?